# Combine Two PHP/MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'd like to combine two php/mysql queries against the wp_posts table using the code below.

However, as you can see, there's an error there with the second post_type. The second post_type is 'post', and is never recognized. :-(

How would I make that an "AND", to gather BOTH the 'membercontent' and 'post' data ? The same question applies to the 'value' statement just below it. 'true' and 'yes'.

```
        <?php $args = array( 
            'post_type' => 'membercontent', 'post',
            'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                             'key'     => 'tt_freemium',
                             'value'   => 'true', 'yes',
                            ),
                           ),
            'orderby' => 'post_date', 
            'order' => 'DESC', 
            'posts_per_page' => '200' );
        `$ourposts = new WP_Query( $args );?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. Duh. Had the answer all along....ARRAYS!

```
<?php $args = array( 
    'post_type' => array ('membercontent', 'post',),
    'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'tt_freemium',
                'value'   => array ('true', 'yes',),
                ),
            ),
    'orderby' => 'post_date', 
    'order' => 'DESC', 
    'posts_per_page' => '200' );
    $ourposts = new WP_Query( $args );?>
```